# ajax request works within the OS X Paw app and cURL, but not as Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, paw-app

I'm relatively new to ajax requests, and am using the Paw app to try to debug one.  The request works fine in Paw itself, and the cURL Paw generates also works.  However, Paw's JavaScript (jQuery) code does not work. It gets a success code (200), but the data returned are

```
{ message: "Error: Not found city", cod: "404" }.
```

It's supposed to return the current weather in Chicago.

This is the request as generated by Paw (except for removing an extraneous linefeed and my Mashape key):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://community-open-weather-map.p.mashape.com/weather",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "lang": "en",
        "lat": "41.8369",
        "lon": "-87.6847",
        "units": "metric",
    },
    headers: {
        "X-Mashape-Authorization": "",
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({

    })
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
})
.always(function() {
    /* ... */
});
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: It actually was a bug in our JavaScript / jQuery code generator. I fixed this bug so now URL params are encoded well: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/JavaScriptjQueryCodeGenerator To update, in Paw go to the Paw menu > Extensions > Check for Extensions Updates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you overwrite the data you query the api with (i.e. the location you are querying the weather for).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://community-open-weather-map.p.mashape.com/weather",
    type: "POST",
    // you set data here:
    data: {
        "lang": "en",
        "lat": "41.8369",
        "lon": "-87.6847",
        "units": "metric",
    },
    headers: {
        "X-Mashape-Authorization": "",
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    // you overwrite data here with an empty object - so remove this!
    data: JSON.stringify({ // <-- remove
        // remove
    }) // <-- remove
})
```

Just remove the second data property and it should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://community-open-weather-map.p.mashape.com/weather",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "lang": "en",
        "lat": "41.8369",
        "lon": "-87.6847",
        "units": "metric",
    },
    headers: {
        "X-Mashape-Authorization": "",
    },
    contentType: "application/json"
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
})
.always(function() {
    /* ... */
});
```

When you overwrite the data with an empty object the Open Weather API does not know which city you are looking for.

Comment: That does appear to be the problem.  The edits to the Paw jQuery code generator removed that section, and also removed "contentType: "application/json".